# Passing a stream between two gulp tasks?

Tags: gulp

I haven't been able to find any documentation of how one does this in gulp, not even sure one should do something like this:

```
var fileStream;

gulp.task('lint', ['glob'], function () {
    var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');

    fileStream.pipe(jshint())
       .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));    

});

gulp.task('glob', function () {
    fileStream = gulp.src([
        './js/**/*.js',
        '!**/node_modules/**'
    ]);
});
```

Is this the best way to do something like this?  Is there a nicer way to 'pass' the stream returned/created by 1 task into some other task(s) so that for something like this we don't duplicate the globbing while still making 'lint' & 'glob' distinct tasks.  Is this even desirable in Gulp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Very common pattern in gulp builds

- patterns are gathered into a single paths variable
- each task begins with a "src" plugin (very often `gulp.src`) and ends with a "sink" plugin (`gulp.dest`, or like in your example, a reporter).

So for your example:

```
var paths = {
    scripts:[
        './js/**/*.js',
        '!**/node_modules/**'
    ],
    css: './css/**'
};

gulp.task('lint', function () {
    var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');

    var stream = gulp.src(paths.scripts)
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));

    return stream;
});

gulp.task('cssmin', function () {
    var stream = gulp.src(paths.css)
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("..."));

    return stream;
});
```

### Why not share streams between tasks?

Gulp's task orchestrator (and soon a new one coming for Gulp 4) is dealing with task dependencies and their execution. [Remember, those tasks can be async](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulptaskname-deps-fn), so you don't want to share a stream that can be used by multiple consumers!

Comment: Sort of makes me wish there could be a 'promise' like aspect to a stream, where the state of the stream at a particular point in time could be passed between consumers and new stream states could be arbitrarily chained off.

Comment: @user2217522, According to the current `gulp` docs, this is finally possible (though it cites the `Q` library in its example, not native `Promise`s), but it does not mention passing the promise as a return value to the next task. You could always declare it at the top level and resolve/reject it in each task, however.